# How to use python to read and extract data from .msg files on linux?

Tags: python, email-attachments, email

I'm trying to extract attachments from .msg files using the following code, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937664/how-to-extract-attachments-from-msg-files). Following is just a part of the code to test whether the attachments are read

```
import email

with open('input/message.msg', 'rb') as fp:
    msg = email.message_from_binary_file(fp)

for part in msg.walk():
    print(part.get_content_type())
    print(part.get_filename())
    print(part.get_content_maintype())
```

I would expect that some of those `print` statements would output something similar to `image/png`, but even if that email message has numerous attachments, the output is simply

```
text/plain
None
text
```

Do you have any hint of what I'm doing wrong? I'm working on a Linux machine with python 3.7.3.

Thanks

**Edit**

I didn't investigate too much but I ended up using the python [module msg-extractor](https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor) which, using the following code, works without any problem

```
import extract_msg
msg = extract_msg.Message("input/email.msg")
for msg in msg.attachments:
    print(msg.save())
```

The attachment class with all the available methods is implement [here](https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor/blob/master/extract_msg/attachment.py), I just needed to store the attachments.
I'll keep the question open hoping for a more relevant answer.

Comment: I am facing the same issues. I am trying to save the attachment instead of reading the data from the message. Actually I get an error for `message_from_binary_file` method, saying it doesn't exist. 

What I did see is - the `.msg` file that I transferred to my linux box is not a multipart message, which is troubling. Per my understanding, if it not a multipart msg, it is being treated only as txt msg. 

if you do a check as below, are you seeing True instead?

`>>> msg.is_multipart()
False`

Comment: I am assuming you are using `.msg` from Outlook. From this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47831826/reading-attributes-of-msg-file it looks like we can't use email module in Python for our purpose.

Comment: @PrasannaSaraswathiKrishnan `msg.is_multipart()` returns `False`. I've updated my question with a temporary solution which works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had the opportunity to try the MSG PY module from an independent soft company. Here's an example:

```
from independentsoft.msg import Message

appointment = Message("e:\\appointment.msg")

print("subject: " + str(appointment.subject))
print("start_time: " + str(appointment.appointment_start_time))
print("end_time: " + str(appointment.appointment_end_time))
print("location: " + str(appointment.location))
print("is_reminder_set: " + str(appointment.is_reminder_set))
print("sender_name: " + str(appointment.sender_name))
print("sender_email_address: " + str(appointment.sender_email_address))
print("display_to: " + str(appointment.display_to))
print("display_cc: " + str(appointment.display_cc))
print("body: " + str(appointment.body))
```